# ASP.NET Identity "Role-based" Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authentication

I understand that I can use claims to make statements about a user:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Peter"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "peter@domain.com"));
```

But how should I store "role-based" claims?  For example:

> The user is a super administrator.

```
claims.Add(new Claim("IsSuperAdmin, "true"));
```

The value parameter "true" feels completely redundant.  How else can this statement be expressed using claims?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is already done for you by the framework. When user is logged in, all user roles are added as claims with claims type being `ClaimTypes.Role` and values are role name.

And when you execute `IPrincipal.IsInRole("SuperAdmin")` the framework actually checks if the claim with type `ClaimTypes.Role` and value `SuperAdmin` is present on the user.

So don't need to do anything special. Just add a user to a role.

Comment: What is the relation between Claims of type Role and AspNetRoles table?

Comment: @Tymski `AspNetRoles` contains list of roles. When user logs in, all these roles are added into the cookie as claims of type `ClaimTypes.Role`. Claims in cookie are short-lived. Records in database are just copied into the cookie.

Comment: I should point out that `IPrincipal.IsInRole("xx")` does not necessarily use `ClaimTypes.Role` when searching for a matching claim.  For example the `WindowsPrincipal` you may receive after doing Windows authentication actually uses the `ClaimTypes.GroupSid` for specifying roles.  Instead use the `ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType` property.

Comment: @Rob Context is king. `IsInRole` is part if `IPrincipal` interface (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/iprincipal.cs,c78f7d29e063c03c,references) and whatever object implements it can do whatever it does. Here we talk about `ClaimsPrincipal` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs,765) And it uses Claims to define roles. If you happen to get `WindowsPrincipal` in Identity framework inside your MVC app, you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: @trailmax `WindowsPrincipal` derives from `ClaimsPrincipal` in .Net 4.5, and I believe you'll find that `WindowsPrincipal` is what you will receive in an ASP.Net Web API (and MVC?) if you configure the application to use windows integrated authentication.  But the point here is that using the specific `ClaimTypes.Role` to drive `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole` is not correct.  See [ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Rob fair enough. I just followed through the source code to this line: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs,72 and hence my reference.

Comment: @Rob though, if you look through [ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs,583) it will lead you to the same constant, pointing to `ClaimsTypes.Role`. But I'm not sure why there is a need to reference the same constant from different properties. Perhaps backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hi @trailmax. It's a little esoteric but note that [ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs,771) uses the property `RoleClaimType` to test if the contained identity has the required claim.  You can see in the reference source for ClaimsIdentity that the backing field for this property defaults to `ClaimsType.Role` but the `WindowsIdentity` constructor passes `ClaimTypes.GroupSid` for this field.  I don't the underlying reason, but this is why it is best to use the `RoleClaimType` property.

Comment: @Rob agreed, one should not be using internal/hidden APIs. But it is good to know what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 21):

You can store roles using the ClaimType [Role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimtypes.role%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SuperAdmin"));
```

Comment: I made the comment above, but it applies here also: it would be more reliable to use the `ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType` property when adding roles.

Comment: What about more than one role?

Comment: Comma separated? Multiple claims with the same type? Other?

Comment: @AlexanderChristov Multiple claims with the same type.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the Role in a claim with a type of ClaimsType.Role and then specify the claim type that contains the role in the ClaimsIdentity as shown below.

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "peter@domain.com"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Peter"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SuperAdmin"),
},
"ApplicationCookie", ClaimTypes.Email, ClaimTypes.Role);
```

This will then allow you to use the `[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]` attribute in your controllers.